# Cannot read property of Null in Lightning Input field

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Lightning force:record data shows following error:

### Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ValuePick__c' of null

```
 <aura:attribute name="UserSkills" type="Object"/>
 <aura:attribute name="UserSkillFields" type="Object"/>
 <force:recordData aura:id="UserRecordCreator" 
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{!v.UserSkills}"
                  targetFields="{!v.UserSkillFields}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  />
 <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm"
                          recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                          objectApiName="GSS_User_Skill__c">
    <lightning:messages />



  <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col">
                <span>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Parameter__c" 
         aura:id="Parameter" value="{!v.UserSkillFields.Parameter__c}"/>

                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <span>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="ValuePick__c" aura:id="ValuePick" value="{!v.UserSkillFields.ValuePick__c}"/>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I write like this error will disappear

> ```
>   <lightning:inputField fieldName="ValuePick__c" aura:id="ValuePick" value=""/>
> ```

Comment: Where is the close tag in the lightning:recordEditForm?
in fact, im not sure you need "force:recordData" to use recordEditForm

Answer (score 0):

force:recordData is missing a recordId, so there's nothing being pulled into v.UserSkillFields. Then when input is attempting to set input value equal to v.UserSkillFields.valueFields, it's drawing a null because nothing has been loaded into that attribute. Try including a recordId attribute in your force:recordData tag, and set it with either force:hasRecordId or an init handler that sets the recordId attr with an Id string. If you're doing the latter you may have to reload recordData with .reloadRecord() to load associated field values. Then you should be able to set value of inputField.

** revision **

On further inspection, it seems like you're trying to default the GSS_User_Skill__c .ValuePick__c field to a parent record's field value. If so, try the following

1. set the parent record (UserSkillFields) id (in init)
2. reload UserSkillFields (also in init)
3. grab the reloaded UserSkillFields via component.get("v.UserSkillFields")
4. explicitly pre-populate lightning:inputField value attribute with reloaded object's corresponding field value (via the force:recordEditForm onLoad() property)

If you'd prefer, [Peter Knolle's blog post](http://peterknolle.com/lightning-record-edit-form/) describes the onLoad() property (and everything else about recordEditForm) superbly.

Comment: its for newly creation of records

Comment: I revised my answer

Comment: itsnot parent record ..same record only

Comment: Then you definitely don't need force:recordData. Just use recordEditForm. Include a lightning:button of type=submit, it'll handle record creation for you.